# Using Knockout to check if undefined

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a template that I would like to use a different bit of HTML based on the control being used:

```
<!-- ko if: Value -->
    ........
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: Value -->
    ........
<!-- /ko -->
```

The intention of this code is to select the first bit if `Value` is defined, the second bit if not. However, this always causes a binding error: `Value is not defined` which I'm fairly sure errors out just checking if the control has `Value` defined.

Is there a better way to use these if statements to check if a binding is defined or not?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `Value` is truly not defined, then you can use `$data.Value` to avoid the "not defined" errors.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic templates. In the view model:

```
self.valueRenderer = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.unwrap(self.Value) ? "valueTemplate" : "noValueTemplate";
});
```

in the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="template: valueRenderer"></div>

<!-- ... -->

<script type="text/html" id="valueTemplate">
    <!-- some complex template... -->
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="noValueTemplate">
    <div>There is no value...</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was the way to go. Currently two controls use the same template, we should refactor it to explicitly use a particular template.